# Совершенный и несовершенный вид глагола — помогите уловить смысл

Tags: семантика, глаголы

Какова смысловая разница в этих двух заголовках (допустим, что статьи в каком-нибудь дачном журнале): *Как выращивать картофель* и *Как вырастить картофель?*

Comment: Порой не понимаю смысла в ваших редакциях (Я говорил именно о подобных предложениях, которые могут быть как заголовками к чему бы то ни было, так и просто текстом где бы то ни было.), но вы художник — вам виднее.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мне кажется, что правильный вариант: **Как (правильно) выращивать картофель**. В этом случае последовательно рассматриваются все этапы ухода за ним и используется глагол несовершенного вида.

**Как вырастить картофель.** Здесь можно получить такой ответ: посадите картофелину в землю (она вырастет сама).

Другой возможный вариант: **Как вырастить хороший урожай картофеля.** В этом случае речь идет о результате, поэтому можно использовать глагол совершенного вида.

Answer (score 4):

**Как выращивать картофель?** В этом случае логично ожидать разносторонний материал для тех, кто планирует *систематически заниматься* выращиванием картофеля и возможно, уже этим занимается.

**Как вырастить картофель?** В этом случае логично ожидать описание последовательности действий (не обязательно с объяснением их логики), простые и конкретные советы тем, кто вознамерился (попробовать) *впервые вырастить* картофель.

Подобное разграничение целевой (причём непрофессиональной) аудитории выбором глаголов заголовка можно встретить и в старых в изданиях статей и книг ("Как строить радиоаппаратуру" или "Как самому сделать радиоприёмник").